# How to remove outlier in Image Rectification (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, ransac, matlab-cvst

I copied this code to do a stereo image rectification.  I am left with an outlier in the image with which I am working, and I'm wondering how I can modify the code to deal with this.  I've played with the confidence and threshold but nothing has worked yet.

```
[fMatrix, epipolarInliers, status] = estimateFundamentalMatrix(...
matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2, 'Method', 'RANSAC', ...
'NumTrials', 1000, 'DistanceThreshold', 0.1, 'Confidence', 99.9);
```

Thanks

Comment: I changed the 'Distance Threshold' to 1 and the outlier went away.  Not sure if this is a robust solution to the issue...

Answer (score 0):

The outlier may be caused by lens distortion. The R2013b release of the Computer Vision System Toolbox includes [camera calibration functionality](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/find-camera-parameters-with-the-camera-calibrator.html) which includes an [undistortImage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/undistortimage.html) function.